# file_get_contents() and cyrillic

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I am trying to get the source of a website using file_get_contents() function, then find something there using regex, and display it on the screen.

The problem is the data I want to extract is cyrillic, and when I look at the output, it is just some strange characters:

```
[6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(83) "ĐĄĐ ĐĐĐĐĐ Đ˘ĐĐ¨ĐĐĐĄĐĐĐ ĐĐĐ ĐĐŁĐĐĐ 28 " } }
```

I also tried converting the encoding of the source into UTF-8 (all my files are utf-8), but I have a lot of those websites, and each of them could have different encodings.

```
$source = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$source = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($source), 'UTF-8', $source);
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

Setting source encoding manually in `iconv` just changes the characters, but it's still not cyrillic.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should try to add the `u` option with preg_match and instead of `[A-Za-z]` you should use `\p{L}`, and instead of `\w` you need to use `[\p{L}\d]`.

Comment: Hm? My regex is: `<div class="tip tipContainer.*?<h5>.*?<a href=".*?>(.*?)<\/a>.*?<span class="tipDate.*?<span>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class="tipLocation">.*?<div class="category">(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class="tipPhoto"><img src="(.*?)".*?<\/span>(.*?)<\/p>/s`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oB5qL5/1

Comment: Then, try `$re = "#<div class=\"tip tipContainer.*?<h5>.*?<a href=\".*?>(.*?)<\/a>.*?<span class=\"tipDate.*?<span>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class=\"tipLocation\">.*?<div class=\"category\">(.*?)<\/div>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class=\"tipPhoto\"><img src=\"(.*?)\".*?<\/span>(.*?)<\/p>#su";`

Comment: Well, now the output is something like \u1231\u5121\u4421

Comment: Try to convert the input with something like: `function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) { 
     $content = file_get_contents($fn); 
      return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 
          mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true)); 
}`